# execution surety and rollback in case of fail, in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, consistency

**MySQL Stored Procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `RMS`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `posTransactionEntry`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `posTransactionEntry`(OUT trxID INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE trxID INT;

INSERT INTO `RMS`.`transaction`
(`MemberID`,`UserID`,`Type`,`UID`)
VALUES (NULL,1,0,'56c54e5c-075d-458d-9845-cf410f8a60ec');

SET trxID=(SELECT ID FROM `transaction` WHERE `transaction`.`UID`='56c54e5c-075d-458d-9845-cf410f8a60ec');
INSERT INTO `RMS`.`transactionentry`
        (
         `TransactionID`,
         `ItemID`,
         `Quantity`,
         `Unitcost`,
         `Price`,
         `SoldPrice`,
         `ReasonID`)
VALUES (trxID,28,10,23.23,10,10,NULL);
UPDATE `transaction` SET `transaction`.`UID`=0 WHERE `transaction`.`ID`=trxID;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

There are four statements in this Stored Procedure. If error occur , how we can find that due to which statement error arise and what is surely that the particular statement execute successfully. If error arise how we can know about that which statement generate error and how we can rollback all executed statement, accordingly.

Means consistency and surety, How we can achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Put each statement which you think can through an error in a `BEGIN and END` block.

You can catch the errors thrown in the blocks and you could assign a variable that would tell you where the error really occurred.

Documentation and example of the `BEGIN and END` can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html).

List of  `error codes` can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html).

The function to know how many rows where updated by the `UPDATE` statement can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).